# Why does R stringdist return Inf in q-gram distance with one string shorter than q?

Tags: r, stringdist

I understand that the q-gram distance is the sum of absolute differences between q-gram vectors of both strings. But I see some weird behavior when one of the strings is shorter than the chosen q.

So for these two strings, while the `qgrams` function is correct:

```
> qgrams("a", "the cat sat on the mat", q = 2)
   th he t  sa on n  ma e   c ca at  s  t  o  m
V1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  3  1  1  1  1
```

The `stringdist` function returns:

```
> stringdist("a", "the cat sat on the mat", q = 2, method = "qgram")
[1] Inf
```

Instead of returning:

```
> sum(qgrams("a", "the cat sat on the mat", q = 2)[2,])
[1] 21
```

Did I miss something or is this a bug? Thanks.

stringdist versions: 0.9.4.1 and 0.9.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `stringdist::stringdist` assumes an undefined (`Inf`) distance when q is larger than the string length.

My reasoning at the time was probably that the map from  {the set of all strings over an alphabet Sigma} to {positive integer vectors of length |Sigma|^q} has no explicit definition if q is less than the input string length. This is also how I wrote it down in the [stringdist paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2014-1/loo.pdf).

`qgrams` maps such cases to the 0-vector, which is indeed inconsistent.

If I take the definition in the paper of [Ukkonen (1992)](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~liptak/ALBioinfo/2011_2012/files/UkkonenTCS92.pdf) mapping to the 0-vector is indeed the right choice, implying a bug in `stringdist`.

Will fix.